# Jquery autocomplete results positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to get the results from autocomplete into a div. Currently, the results are floating to the left corner of the page. I need to results to be just below the input search box. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:blue;float:right;">
<p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
     $(".auto").
autocomplete({ source: "search.php", minLength: 1})      

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is usually caused by the CSS layout of your page affecting the positioning of the library. As such we'd need to see a more complete version of the HTML and related CSS in order to help you

Comment: Rory, I have added the entire code. thanks

Comment: Have  you tried changing the class name?  I think auto is a reserved word.  Just a suggestion.  And isn't the syntax for autocomplete this: $(".myclass").autocomplete(url, {params});

Comment: tried changing auto class to myauto, still the results are appearing on the top left.